# How to sort Microsoft Azure database table data BY DATE

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, azure

I am trying to sort the rows in my table by the latest date first.

```
var userParkingHistory = from j in dataGateway.SelectAll() select j ;
userParkingHistory = userParkingHistory.Where(ParkingHistory => ParkingHistory.username == User.Identity.Name);
return View(userParkingHistory);
```

I can currently display the rows sorted by the username but I also want it to sort by the latest date first.

In my gateway, this is how I select the list:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return data.ToList();
    }
```

Where and How do I sort the data according to the latest date first ?

This is how I define my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParkingHistory] (
[parkingHistoryId] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[carparkId]        INT           NULL,
[username]         VARCHAR (255) NULL,
[date]             DATETIME      NULL,
[description]      VARCHAR (255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([parkingHistoryId] ASC)
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Linq has orderby:

```
var userParkingHistory = from j orderby j.date in dataGateway.SelectAll() select j ;
```

Alsi, List has various extension methods to sort itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var userParkingHistory = dataGateway.SelectAll().Where(p => p.username == User.Identity.Name).OrderBy(p => p.date).ToList();
return View(userParkingHistory);
```